How to use a code signing identity that doesn't match the Development Team in Xcode?
I'm trying to build an app via Xcode with a very specific "code signing identity" (supervisionIdentity-COMPANY_NAME.organization) that my MDM gave me. I also develop in a Development Team that didn't create this code signing identity. Therefore, Xcode doesn't like this and shows an error when trying to build the app:

In other terms, how can I use a "code signing identity" that didn't get created by the Development Team in here:


You need to add the developer/distribution certificate for that team/provisioning profile to your Mac's keychain

It would help if you told your DMD to export the Personal Information Exchange (.p12) file in the Keychain Access, which is related to the provisioning above. I am assuming that it could be Distribution certificate because of your file prefix APPSTORE_CONNECT

After you receive this .p12 file, click to install it on your keychain and you're able to go forward.
